# Чи правильно використовувати слово "підписка" для регулярної оплати послуги в інтернеті

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Чи є правильним слово "підписка" для багаторазової, регулярної оплати певної послуги в інтернеті. Чи варто використовувати слово "передплата"? Наприклад, можливість переглядати відео з сервісу, виплачуючи кожного місяця Н-гривень. Згідно з деякими джерелами:

> Слово підписка означає «затвердження підписом людини якогось
>   зобов’язання додержуватись певних правил чи виконувати якусь вимогу».
>   А коли хтось хоче одержувати газети й журнали або збірку творів
>   якогось письменника, за що треба наперед заплатити певну суму грошей,
>   це зветься передплатою

Та чи є "передплата" підходящим словом в цьому випадку? Послуга може бути безкоштовною, а оплата може проводитись регулярно і автоматично. Це трохи відрізняє його від передплати газет і журналів.

Comment: Сторінка [«Як назвати оформлення отримання новин в мережі?»](/q/2551) часом не про те саме?

Comment: Сторінка схожа, хоча питання там більш загальне. Підписка на друзів, новини може мати свої відповідні слова (додати у друзі, стежити за новинами). Нажаль там немає однозначної відповіді для оплати послуг чи сервісів.

Comment: Чим слово послуги відрізняється від services?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko мабуть нічим, наприклад ви можете оформити підписку на Windows і платити кілька доларів в місяць за користування. *Windows is a service*

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, наск. я зн., «service» може позначати не лише послугу, а й установу, що надає послуги; плюс ще є інші значення, як-от (військова, церковна) служба, подання (м'яча в спортивних іграх), (столовий) сервіз; тобто загалом набір значень у слова «service» ширший, ніж у «послуга». (Але у фразі «для оплати послуг чи сервісів» слово «сервісів» справді необов'язкове, бо тут фактично виходить «послуг чи послуг». Хоча не виключено, що колись слово «сервіс» під впливом Інтернету/англійської набуде іншого, вужчого тлумачення — «цифрова послуга, інтернет-послуга», але поки ще ні, здається.)

Comment: Я розумію слово сервіс, як говірку (slang). Мета мого коментаря звернути на це увагу.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Мабуть, словом *"підписка"* таки можна послуговуватись.

[Лариса Колібаба](https://scholar.google.com.ua/citations?user=OluMd1AAAAAJ) в одній зі статей [пише](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine62-20.pdf):

> В українській мові активно вживані віддієслівні іменники з суфіксом *-к-*, для яких основним є предметне значення (продукту, наслідку дії, об’єкта, предмета, за допомогою якого здійснюють дію, зрідка місця дії: *виписка, в’язка, грілка, закладка, збірка, пересадка, підтяжка, посилка, присипка*). **Такі утворення не суперечать cловотвірним нормам української мови.**

Натомість:

> Щодо вираження значення упредметненої дії, то значна частина іменників із суфіксом *-к-* є прямими лексичними запозиченнями з російської мови, напр.: *блокіровка, буксировка, оцинковка, розбраковка, стажировка*. Вони є паралельними утвореннями до питомих дериватів української мови на -ння, пор.: *браковка — бракування, гравіровка — гравірування, промивка — промивання, прошивка — прошивання, стажировка — стажування, страховка — страхування* і под.

Думаю, іменник *"підписка"* належить до першої з наведених груп, адже позначає наслідок дії *"підписатися"* (подібно до *"виписатися"* - *"виписка"*).

Ще одну підставу не відкидати слово "підписка" можна знайти у [Максима Вакуленка](http://studia-linguistica.knu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/2010-4-353-359-%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%9C.%D0%9E..pdf):

> **Щодо вживання суфікса *~к~*.** З одного боку, є багато прикладів, які підтверджують важливість цього суфікса: *постановка* (а не *постанова*), *підставка* (а не *підстава*), *посадка* (літака, дерев – а не *посада* інженера) [...]. З іншого боку, фіналі *"~ка"* та *"~ння"* надають слову різних значень: *затримка* (процесу – на противагу *затриманню* злочинця), [...] *в'язка* (на противагу *в'язанню*), *пробіжка* (а не *пробігання*), [...] *описка* (на противагу *описанню*), *записка, зупинка, підбірка* (на противагу *підбиранню*) [...]. Як бачимо, **слова з морфом *~ка* мають глибоке коріння в нашій мові, і їх заміна іншими формами призвела б до спотворення змісту**. Тому ми погоджуємося з висновками праці [Пілецький 1994, 83], що і цей тип віддієслівних похідних має перспективу в українській науковій мові.

Справді, є слово *"записка"*, утворене від *"записати"* - не думаю, що його слід вважати калькою з російської та уникати. Чому ж тоді по-іншому ставитися до *"підписки"*, утвореної від *"підписати(сь)"*?

Проте я не філолог і, звісно, можу помилятися. Якщо хтось розуміється на цьому краще - поділіться своїми думками)

Наостанок, ось декілька прикладів вживання слова у значенні, про яке запитує автор.

[Уніан](https://www.unian.ua/economics/transport/10699047-netflix-v-sviti-avto-canoo-hoche-stvoriti-pershiy-servis-pidpiski-na-elektrokari.html):

> Сервіси підписки стають все більш популярними. За допомогою підписки можна отримувати доступ до музики, фільмів, ігор і додатків.

[ZN,UA](https://dt.ua/TECHNOLOGIES/apple-predstavila-noviy-servis-pidpiski-na-novini-306577_.html):

> Підписка на сервіс буде коштувати від 9,99 доларів в місяць, замість 8 тисяч доларів на рік, які потрібно було б заплатити за підписку на кожен журнал окремо.

[Студвей](https://studway.com.ua/servis-elektronnikh-zamitok/):

> Компанія оголосила про можливість безкоштовної підписки на її преміум-версію для викладачів та студентів.

Comment: Вказані посилання на сайти новин, як джерела не можуть бути за достовірні приклади використання слів. На тих сайтах забагато помилок для цього.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko розумію. Я вагалася, додавати приклади із сайтів, чи ні - особливо той, де йде мова про 9,99 доларів _в місяць_ (а не _на місяць_). Зрештою, залишила. Не як аргумент на користь слова "підписка" (аргументи вище), і не як взірець бездоганної української, а радше як ілюстрацію до теми. Хоча якщо мені підскажуть джерела, яким можна довіряти, я старатимусь добирати приклади там. Чи крім словників і статей мовознавців нічого й немає?